# Sound system on Volvo V40 MY 2013

Tags: volvo, audio

Has anyone on the Continent managed to upgrade a factory installed "Performance" sound system on a Volvo V40 MY 2013 to "High Performance" ?

**EDIT:** (Included from comments)

Volvo supplies several editions of sound systems to its cars. The most simple and "naked" edition is the one called "Performance". It has neither USB port, nor Bluetooth. My car is supplied with this sound system. On the contrary, the edition called "High Performance" incorporates these characteristics (USB, BT), but the dealer in Greece declares that an upgrade is not possible, at least now. Thus, I am looking on information if someone has succeeded to do this, on his/her own means. I am looking on the Continent because UK cars are supplied with "High Performance" as minimum.

Comment: What specific issues are you having or what would you like to have done? To make for a better question, please let us know your end goals and issues you are having and I'm sure someone will be able to help you.